# Powershell HTTP POST method within same session

Tags: powershell, httprequest

I have a limited understanding in html, i am trying to automate a form filling like the following:

```
$JSONLOGIN = @'
{"@type":"login",
"email":"xxx@xxx.com",
"password":"xxxx"
}
'@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://xxxxxxx/api/users/login" -Method Post -Body $JSONLOGIN -ContentType "application/json"

$response

$JSONADDRATE = @'
{
"@type":"add",
"supplierRef":"S020893",
"buyerRef":"520170509082555",
"fiRef":"7769",
"rateDate":"2017-09-15T14:11:04.684Z",
"rateType":"fixedRate",
"spFee":2,
"comFee":1,
"fiMarginOver":3,
"ttofc":0,"isTtofc":false,
"fixedRate":2,"primeLiborRate":0,
"oneWTenorRate":0,
"oneMTenorRate":0,
"twoMTenorRate":0,
"threeMTenorRate":0,
"sixMTenorRate":0,
"nineMTenorRate":0,
"oneYTenorRate":0}
'@


$response2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://xxxxxxx/api/ubiq/rates/add" -Method Post -Body $JSONADDRATE -ContentType "application/json"

$response2
```

The responses are returning like that:

```
$response

isSessionValid : True
data           : @{email=xxx@xxxx.com; id=5988ad267520a62df46af0a4; name=xxx Back Office}
isSuccessful   : True
isError        : False
isAllowed      : True
message   

$response2

isSessionValid : False
data           : 
isSuccessful   : False
isError        : False
isAllowed      : False
message
```

Obviously the login session is being lost when jumping into the second link (Hence isSessionValid: false), how can i keep the session alive?

Comment: There are keepalive and sessionvariable parameters.  I would suggest reading the documentation on them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-SessionVariable` parameter creates a `Web Request Session Object` basically saving your session in the current `PowerShell` session.

In order to take advantage of that try this:

```
In the first Request add a -SessionVariable parameter and give it a string
(any string without the preceding $) then in second Request pass that string 
(this time with a preceding $) to the -WebSession parameter.
```

Comment: I don't know why anyone would downvote you, but this worked.  For the downvoter, why?